# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-magic-bin

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, python-magic, libmagic

I was trying to use UnstructuredURLLoader of LangChain to load URLs,

which has dependencies of Libmagic, python-magic, python-magic-bin

I have successfully installed Libmagic and python-magic. During the installation of python-magic-bin, there is an error

```
!pip3 install python-magic-bin
```

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-magic-bin (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-magic-bin
```

```
loader = UnstructuredURLLoader(urls=["https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/tata-motors-mahindra-gain-certificates-for-production-linked-payouts-11281691.html"])

data=loader.load()
```

```
libmagic is unavailable but assists in filetype detection on file-like objects. Please consider installing libmagic for better results.

Error fetching or processing https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/tata-motors-mahindra-gain-certificates-for-production-linked-payouts-11281691.html, exception: Invalid file. The FileType.UNK file type is not supported in partition.
```

```
!pip3 install libmagic
```

```
Requirement already satisfied: libmagic in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (1.0)
```

I want to load text from news websites using unstructured and getting above error,can some one help me out